# Como armazenar o valor de um input em uma variável e mostrá-la

Tags: javascript, html

Eu estou tentando pegar um valor de alguns inputs com JavaScript para mostra-los em uma ordem especifica.

```
<form id="formulario" name="" method="" action="">

        <p><h2 id="titulo-form">Dados do Livro</h2></p>
        <p><label for="nome">Nome do Autor:</label>
            <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome"maxlength="80"/></p>

        <p><label for="sobre">Sobrenome do Autor:</label>
            <input type="text" name="sobre" id="sobre"maxlength="80"/></p>

        <p><label for="titulo">Título:</label>
            <input type="text" name="titulo" id="titulo"maxlength="80"/></p>
```

No caso, eu gostaria de mostrar a ordem: Sobrenome do autor > Nome do Autor > Título

Não tenho muita experiência com JS, então o básico que tentei foi armazenar os inputs as variáveis desta forma, e linkar a função gerar ao submit do form, porém, não sei como retorna-la

```
function gerar() {
  var nomeAutor = document.getElementsById('nome'); 
  var sobreNome = document.GetElementById('sobre');
  var titulo = document.getElementsById('titulo');
}
```

Comment: Queres mostrar sempre que mudem? ou quando a página carregue? ou quando o formulário for submetido?

Comment: Quando o formulário for submetido

Comment: Donizete, poste o JS da tentativa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podes ir buscar o valor de cada input com

```
form.querySelector(`[name="${name}"]`).value
```

e depois para criar uma string com esses valores podes fazer por exemplo

```
form.querySelector(`[name="${name}"]`).value
```

Exemplo:

```js
const form = document.getElementById('formulario');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const [sobre, nome, titulo] = ['sobre', 'nome', 'titulo'].map(
    name => form.querySelector(`[name="${name}"]`).value
  );
  alert(`${sobre}, ${nome} - ${titulo}`);
});
```

```html
<form id="formulario" name="" method="" action="">

  <p>
    <h2 id="titulo-form">Dados do Livro</h2>
  </p>
  <p><label for="nome">Nome do Autor:</label>
    <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" maxlength="80" /></p>

  <p><label for="sobre">Sobrenome do Autor:</label>
    <input type="text" name="sobre" id="sobre" maxlength="80" /></p>

  <p><label for="titulo">Título:</label>
    <input type="text" name="titulo" id="titulo" maxlength="80" /></p>
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar um alert simples do Javascript na tela imprimindo as suas variáveis:

```
Alert('  Sobrenome do autor > Nome do Autor > Título'+ sobreNome + nomeAutor + titulo);
```